# Where should I define namedtuple classes in Python - which namespace?

Tags: python, pickle, namedtuple

Namedtuples are useful in Python to name small collections of data.

Take for example this namedtuple:

```
import collections
sesameEpisodeNTC = collections.namedtuple('sesameEpisodeNTC', 
                                          'lead_character', 'has_elmo')
se0 = sesameEpisodeNTC(lead_character='bigbird', has_elmo=False)
```

Can the class definition ('sesameEpisodeNTC = '...) be made an attribute of another class?  I'd prefer to keep some namedtuples inside classes to avoid cluttering the module namespace.  But this causes problems with pickling (cPickle, dill), which is a showstopper.

Similarly, I've noticed the first parameter of the namedtuple class definition, the typename (i.e. 'sesameEpisodeNTC') must be the name of the class, otherwise pickling does not work. (using both 2.7 and 3.4)  That duplication is not ideal.  Are there other best practices for the typename parameter, and does it affect code beside pickling code?

Are there other not-widely-documented corner cases I'm missing with namedtuples?  It's  annoying that some of python's most useful data structures have sharp corners that can snag on parts of the stdlib.

Comment: Keep in mind the parameter value  *is* the true name of the class; the fact that the variable you use to *reference* the class object is usually the same as the class name is just a convention, one reinforced by the fact that the `class` statement uses the same name for both.

Comment: What @chepner said, plus the variable name and the parameter value must be the same for `pickle` to work. Also `pickle` only works for classes defined at the module level, so you're stuck with the so-called namespace pollution since that means you can't make the `namedtuple` definitions an attribute of another class. You might be able to define your own module-level class that was a generic or meta namespace definition class which _was_ pickleable to get around some of this.

Comment: Should collections.namedtuple document that for pickle to work, the variable name and the parameter name must be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the `namedtuple` definition at the module level, `dill` can pickle the class with the `namedtuple` class object as an attribute.  Of course, this doesn't help you "reduce clutter".  I think the answer is no.  At the moment, you can not define a `namedtuple` inside a class and have it pickled by default.

```
>>> import collections
>>> nt = collections.namedtuple('nt',['one','two'])
>>> nt
<class '__main__.nt'>
>>> 
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> dill.copy(nt)
<class '__main__.nt'>
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   cnt = nt
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.cnt
<class '__main__.nt'>
>>> f.cnt(1,2)
nt(one=1, two=2)
>>> 
>>> dill.copy(f)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10f1b5850>
>>> dill.copy(Foo)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>>
```

There is a ticket/issue on `dill` github to be able to do better, but right now no -- you'd have to live with module-level `namedtuples` -- and yes, they need to have the same name as the first parameter of the `namedtuple`.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  Should the stdlib prominently document that all namedtuples should be defined at module level if you hope to use stdlib pickle with them?  Thanks for dill, btw - it's great.

Comment: I think the docs for `pickle` may need some clarification for certain objects, especially newer ones like `namedtuple`.